# Force 2 image links in same line

Tags: php, javascript

I've got a link with 4 images and I need it to show the images in a 2x2 format... I've done this:

```
echo '<a id="myImgId" class="myImg"  href="javascript: submitform()">';
    while  (($num_images > 0) && ($num_images <= $max_images))
    {
        if($num_images == ($max_images/2)) { echo '<br />';}
        echo '<img class="nomarge" alt="" id="updateimage' . $num_images . '" name="adBanner' . $num_images . '" src="rsz_image' . $num_images . '.jpg" />';
        $num_images--;
    }
echo '</a>';
```

Ok, the br separates the 2 images top and 2 down. 
My problem is that when the images sizes are too big, I've got one image per line and not 2. I want to force them to be in the same line, even when the window is too small....

1st try

```
.myImg {
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```

2nd try

```
.myImg {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

3rd try

```
.myImg {
     overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: set .myImg {float:left}; and make sure the width of the container can accommodate two images.

Comment: The PHP seems irrelevant here. Can you post an example of the rendered HTML?

Comment: well, I know the width of the container is too big, I just want to create an horizontal scrollbar if the width is too big

Comment: Instead of applying the overflow styling to the href, you could apply them to the container holding the images to give a scroll bar.

Comment: how do I do that @Fred ?

Comment: I'm not too sure how you are laying it out. But, for example, if you place all the images within a div tag and then apply a width and overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not generate a table?

Simpler and faster, also more... code friendly.

```
        <tr>
             <td>
                <img />
             </td>
             <td>
                <img />
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img />
            </td>
            <td>
                <img />
            </td>
         </tr>
```

Comment: Adding more structure to a document isn't a solution I'll endorse. Css should define presentation, HTML should define the document. You shouldn't add markup in order to appease presentation.

Comment: Adding 100 lines of css to avoid some basic html is not exactly the solution. Also it is in most cases browser dependent. The way you say it you can make a whole site using just span elements. You can add classes and display block/table-cells on them so you simulate divs or tables. Is THIS what you endorse?? I agree that if you can reliably do something without adding markup is fine... but I really don't think is the case here. I personally hate tables myself. Still... this is a classic scenario when they do the work.

Comment: Well, for one, it shouldn't take 100 lines of CSS. For two, yes, if that is what it takes, it absolutely is the solution. Separation of concerns.

Comment: The correct css solution for this requires 4 elements with display blocks, floats, dimensions, positions, and possibly (depending on cases) overflows. If you do this in 2 lines, browser independent (just test on IE 6), and without pulling your hair out... well... gg. If you do this please do post the solution... I really really wanna see it.

Comment: "The correct css solution for this" There is always more than one way to do something. There is never only one "correct css solution". I have a feeling you are very inexperienced with CSS. That's why you have to fall back to adding structure to achieve presentation.

Comment: There are 9999 solutions to this. I am talking about a stable one. Maybe not the best but first it comes in mind. I have a feeling you are very inexperienced since you don't know how unstable it can be. Let me guess... you only test in webkit browsers :)). Also... where your answer?

Comment: The mere fact that you are continuing to argue that it is better to pollute the document with added structure for the sake of presentation will tell anyone with any actual knowledge on the subject all they need to know.

Comment: Last comment... I actually have better things to do and OP is probably out. Still didn't find the answer? Let me guess... you read one article that says that so it is automatically correct. I'm tired of what stack has become... another place where ppl disregard clear solutions without providing alternatives. Good luck to you my friend... you once again proved my point that ppl are ignorant fools by default. Maybe after 5-6 more years of experience and more than one articles read you'll reconsider.

Comment: this doesn't revolve my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a id="myImgId" class="myImgId" href="javascript: submitform()">';
echo '<ul>';
    while  (($num_images > 0) && ($num_images <= $max_images))
    {                                                                     
        if($num_images == ($max_images/2)) { echo '</ul><ul style="padding:0 0 0 0;border:0 0 0 0;margin:0 0 0 0;">';}
        echo '<li><img class="nomarge" alt="" id="updateimage' . $num_images . '" name="adBanner' . $num_images . '" src="rsz_image' . $num_images . '.jpg" width="' . $ver  . '" height="' . $hor . '"/><li>';
        $num_images--; 
    }
echo '</ul>';
echo '</a>';
```

CSS

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border:  0;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: inline;   
}

li {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;  
    display: table-cell;      

}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Simple as that... I guess, it worked for me! Thank you all

Comment: Omfg...  display: table-cell; (default on td), table-layout: fixed; display: inline; (simulate defaults on table). Not only that you added markup, what was bad in some ppls opinion (ul and li), but you also used a list to simulate a table. Is the same answer like mine but with mixed up elements and so much extra css. I'm glad you fixed your problem but this is wrong for so many reasons. Crush ma man if you voted this up and mine down... you really are the lamest programmer wanna be. Replace ul with table, li with tds, add tr in while. Then delete all css and you get the same thing with 0 css.

Comment: First of all, this is not a up or down vote question, I voted up even thought it was -1 at the time. By the way, the difference btw the 2 answers is... my works, yours doesn't... :\

Comment: Ty for the vote... although if it didn't solve your problem it was no need for it. The only possible reason why mine didn't work while yours did is that you did something wrong :). Again... if that solved your problem I'm glad for you... I just tell you that it is a... not so good way to do it. If it is a small application, where you work alone is ok, but in a "bigger" environment that will cause so so so many problems. For example a simple hide show toggle made by some1 else requires that that guy knows you used display table-cell on a li. That's not a good practice.

Comment: didn't solve, but helped. Maybe latter I'll give it another try ;)

Comment: I'll post you a complete answer after work if I don't forget.